# File in java not downloading correctly

Tags: java, web-applications, web

I want to download a file from a Server into a client machine. But i want the file to be downloaded from a browser : I want the file to be saved at the Downloads Folder.

Im using the following code to download files.

```
public void descarga(String address, String localFileName) {

OutputStream out = null;
URLConnection conn = null;
InputStream in = null;
try {
    // Get the URL
    URL url = new URL(address);
    // Open an output stream to the destination file on our local filesystem

    out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(localFileName));
    conn = url.openConnection();
    in = conn.getInputStream();

    // Get the data
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int numRead;
    while ((numRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, numRead);
    }
    // Done! Just clean up and get out
} catch (Exception exception) {
    exception.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (in != null) {
            in.close();
        }
        if (out != null) {
            out.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        // Shouldn't happen, maybe add some logging here if you are not
        // fooling around ;)
    }
    }
```

It works but unless i specify the absolute path it does not download the file, therefore is useless to use from different clients with different browsers, because the webpage does not even prompts the message that lets the user know that a file is being downloaded. What can i add to get that to work?

Thanks

Comment: May I ask what a browser has to do with this? If you do not specify an absolute path, the file will be saved on the current working directory.

Comment: I mean that if the browser has My Documents/ configured as the Downloads Folder, i want the file to be downloaded there

Comment: I have 4 different browsers running on my machine. How should a Java program know about this? I am confused about what you want.

Comment: Not an answer but you shouldn't open the output file until after you have obtained the input stream. If that fails, you don't want empty files lying around.